# Error en programa para realizar divisiones a través de restas

Tags: c++

El usuario ingresa el dividendo y el divisor y el programa ha de devolver el cociente a través de una función que hace restas. Me devuelve el siguiente error: Realmente es un problema de que no realiza el programa en lugar de un problema de sintaxis

```
 Failed example:
        printf '20 100' | ./program
    Expected:
        0
    Got:
        20
    **********************************************************************
    File "", line 5, in __main__
    Failed example:
        printf '100 20' | ./program
    Expected:
        5
    Got:
        0
```

Adjunto el código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int division(int a, int b);
int main(){
  int a, b;
  cin >> a >> b;
  cout << division(a, b);
}
int division(int a, int b){
  int temporal=a;
  for(int i=0; a>=b; i++){
    if ((temporal - b)<=0){
     temporal -= 4; 
    }
    return i;
  }
}
```

Comment: Efectivamente. No obstante me sigue sin funcionar el código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí una posible solución a tu duda utilizando un `while()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int division(int a, int b);

int main(){
  int a, b;
  std::cin >> a >> b;
  std::cout << division(a, b);
}

int division(int dividendo, int divisor){
    int resto, cociente;
    // COMPRUEBA QUE LOS NÚMEROS SEAN MAYOR A 0
    if ( dividendo > 0 && divisor > 0 ){
        cociente = 0;
        resto = dividendo;
        while ( resto >= divisor ){
            resto -= divisor;
            cociente++;
        }
        return cociente;
    } else
        printf( "\n   ERROR: Ambos n%cmeros deben ser mayores que cero.", 163 );
    return 0;
}
```

Para éste ejemplo se ha tomado los siguientes números:

```
dividendo: 26
divisor: 5
cociente: 5
```

Esta respuesta está basada del siguiente [enlace](https://www.abrirllave.com/c/ejercicio-division-entera-con-restas-sucesivas.php)